# Custom Validator

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I want to use a validator to compare 2 text box in such a way that ,

If V is in Text box 1,  means User must type any of the numbers prefix V in Textbox 2 (V00001 to V00050).Other than V ,if they type any other Letters means error message must be shown.

Just like that if C is in TextBox 1 means user must type C00001 in TextBox2.(or any number from C00001 TO C00050)
iF S is in textbox 1 means,User must Type S00001(S00001 TO S00050)

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code... what have you tried, what pitfalls did you face, what error did you encounter? Please refrain from asking for code without demonstrating any effort.

Answer (score 1):

Use this method:

```
// C#
public static bool IsValid(string textBox1Text, string textBox2Text)
{
    return new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^" + textBox1Text + "000[0-4][0-9]$").IsMatch(textBox2Text) || string.Equals(textBox2Text, textBox1Text + "00050");
}

' VB
Public Shared Function IsValid(ByVal textBox1Text As String, ByVal textBox2Text As String) As Boolean
    Return New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^" + textBox1Text + "000[0-4][0-9]$").IsMatch(textBox2Text) OrElse String.Equals(textBox2Text, textBox1Text + "00050")
End Function
```